# how to correspond between threads

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

Today I am taught to use std::future and promise in c++11 thread. I learnt that they can be used for correspondence between threads. But when I have a try on them, the IDEA told me that the function 'get_future' can be used only one time. Besides, the function 'std::future' is just the same. So how can I use the two correctly to build a bridge between two threads and let them communicate with each other more than one time? Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: generally you use `condition_variable`'s to signal updated shared state between threads.

Comment: And as usual cppreference provides a simple example illustrating the idea. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Deoends on the info you want to communicate and whether you want the consuming thread to wait. E.g. if there's a thread that every 2 seconds prints out the current variable set from the other thread, a `std::atomic` could be all you need, but communication via atomics is very limited. barriers/semaphores may be another alternative for certain scenarios, but that's C++20 stuff. You may want to check, what's available in the concurrency support library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: thank you all above. I will try to describe my question much more clearly next time, posting with my code. Today I deleted the code using promise-futire, replacing by using condition_variable. It worked! I create a global variable,  and when I need to operate it, I awaken the thread using "notify". It seems that it can work correctly compared to my expectations. Oh,  forget to tell that I am writing a TCP server through c++11 thread.